# Wercker deploy to cloud server - pernission denied on deploy script

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, wercker

I am a wercker noob. I am trying to deploy the result of my maven build to a server via scp. I have a simple script to achieve this however the build process does not have permission to execute it.

**deploy output**

```
cd $WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR
$ export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/wercker/steps/wercker/script/0.0.0"
$ export WERCKER_STEP_ID="2bffb2c2-6e60-4197-89b8-46c0ed566cdc"
$ export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
$ export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="$WERCKER_REPORT_DIR/$WERCKER_STEP_ID/numbers.ini"
$ export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="$WERCKER_REPORT_DIR/$WERCKER_STEP_ID/message.txt"
$ export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="$WERCKER_REPORT_DIR/$WERCKER_STEP_ID/artifacts"
$ mkdir -p $WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR
$ export WERCKER_STEP_TEMP="/tmp/$WERCKER_STEP_ID"
$ source '/wercker/wercker-build-essentials/init.sh'
$ mkdir -p $WERCKER_STEP_TEMP
$ ./myapp-deploy/src/scripts/deploy_ocean.sh
-bash: ./myapp-deploy/src/scripts/deploy_ocean.sh: Permission denied
```

And the deploy script

```
$ ls -lrt (git bash on windows laptop)
total 1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 hugo  Administ      593 Feb 16 23:31 deploy_ocean.sh
```

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

TARGET_DIR="/tmp/deploy"
TARGET_DEPLOY="x.x.x.x"
SCP=/usr/bin/scp
#WAR_FILE="../../../myapp-war/target/myapp.war"

##variables for testing
WAR_FILE="../../../myapp-war/test.txt"
########

deploy()
{
echo echoing deploying $WAR_FILE
logger deploying $WAR_FILE
$SCP -i $WERCKER_PRIVATE $WAR_FILE root@$TARGET_DEPLOY:TARGET_DIR
logger deploy over
logger echoing deploy over
}

##echo variables
#echo_variables
##deploy the app
echo attempting deploy
logger attempting deploy
deploy
```

Comment: Hi man. You want to deploy on a digital ocean server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation at line 5.
http://devcenter.wercker.com/articles/werckeryml/validate.html

Comment: Hi Joost, my original problem was i misunderstood deploy process. I expected the deploy to happen automatically! y indentation was fine, just copy and paste error. Now that I am actually calling the deploy-to-target function i have updated question with new (real!) issue